# Crear formato fecha en R

Tags: r

Tengo una columna con este formato de fecha,(2012 -01) con todos los meses del año y quiero convertirla de formato numérico a fecha para crear una serie de tiempo, ¿alguna idea?

Traté de esta forma pero me marca error

```
datos <- as.Date(datos$fecha, tryFormats = c(%Y%-%m%))
```

> Error: unexpected SPECIAL in "datos <- as.Date(datos$fecha, tryFormats = c(%Y%"

Comment: A que te refieres con formato numérico? Podrías poner un ejemplo de la salida que necesitas?

Comment: Hola Tao! Es algo similar a esto lo que buscas? `d = paste("2012-0", c(1:9), "-01", sep = "")

d1 = as.Date(d, "%Y-%m-%d")
` . Dale una mirada a la documentación en caso de dudas: `?as.Date`

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

De partida, el uso de `%Y%` está mal. El formato de fecha en R para año de 4 dígitos es `%Y` (revisa `?strptime` para ver todos los formatos disponibles.

Debes seleccionar un día del mes para realizar la conversión con R base (hay otras librerías que permiten tiempos de año/mes, sin día - `zoo`  con `yearmon` por ejemplo).

Dicho esto, la solución es utilizar el siguiente esquema para `as.Date`:

```
fecha <- "2012 -01"
as.Date(paste0(fecha,'-01'), format = '%Y -%m-%d')
```